# How can I iterate between dynamic columns with v-slot in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I have dynamically changing columns in data-table. For example an col1, col2, col3-value column. How can I made dynamically the `<template v-slot:item.col1="item"> and <template v-slot:item.col2="item">....`

Comment: You can define multiple templates so just put both in your table components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple templates in your table. So you can just define one for every col in your table.

Here is a working example with the deserts example in the vuetify API.

```js
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template v-slot:item.calories=" { item }">
      {{ item.calories.toFixed(2) }}
    </template>

    <template v-slot:item.fat=" { item }">
      {{ item.fat.toFixed(1) }}
    </template>

    <template v-slot:item.carbs=" { item }">
      {{ item.carbs.toFixed(3) }}
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Hello",
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```